# Cant install UpWork Team app on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, gksu

I tried to install the UpWork Team app on Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit) but have problem with dependencies.

This deb package ask me to install: `gksu`, `libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5)` and   `libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.14-0)`

I found `libgcrypt11` ([64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb)/[32](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_i386.deb)) and installed it. But I can't find `libgnutls26` which I also need to be installed for `gksu`.

*Where can I download it, or which repository I need to add?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try first: 
`sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11 libgnutls26 gksu`
 because these packages are available in the repositories so they should be installed automatically.

Comment: `E: For package «libgnutls26» no installation candidate`

I think i missing some core repository. Which of it contains this packages?

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. In Ubuntu 15.04 there are new versions of the packages so the names have changed. Now you need to do: sudo apt-get install libgnutls-deb0-28 libgcrypt20 gksu but now you probably get an error from Upteam being a wrong version so you'll need a version that works on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Thank you. This helps me, libraries installed seccessful, but as you said, now problem with version.  I think this resolve problem with libraries installation asked in question, now problem only with their app.

Comment: It's  not working with me !

Comment: @Spartan What's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Problem resolved using a mirror package:

**For x86_64/amd64 (64bit)**

```
$ sudo wget https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Download a package [here](https://www.upwork.com/downloads/new-team-application): "Debian-based 64-bit (Standard)"

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core

$ sudo gdebi upwork_amd64.deb
```

**For i386 (32bit)**

```
$ sudo wget https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_i386.deb

$ dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_i386.deb
```

Download a package [here](https://www.upwork.com/downloads/new-team-application): "Debian-based 32-bit (Standard)"

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core

$ sudo gdebi upwork_i386.deb
```

Comment: You don't need gdebi. The Software Centre can handle deb files with dependencies.

Comment: Links are broken. This helps me again... :)

https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4_i386.deb

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit follow these two steps:

1. Download old version of nss libraries.

   ```
   sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
   sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-1d_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
   ```
2. Install downloaded packages.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libnss3*
   ```